# How to determine the duration for which a file was accessed/modified a program?

Tags: windows, powershell, encryption, monitoring, io

I would like to measure the speed of encryption performed by a utility on a `Windows 10` box. Since there are no other ways in the utility itself to do this, I would like to know if I can determine how long it took for the utility to encrypt a certain file using I/O access monitoring. Intuitively, the longer it held the ''lock'' on the file, the longer it took to encrypt it. I have searched quite a bit on the Internet on how to do this but couldn't find even remotely relevant answers.

Is it possible to monitor how long a process held a "write lock" on a certain file or accessed the file? If yes, could you please provide an example? Perhaps it is possible to write a `powershell` script to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You are asking folks to write stuff from scratch for you. That is really not what these Q&A forums are for.

The rule is you must show what effort you've tried, where you've searched, show your code, and any errors you are getting.

Measuring code execution is not unique to PowerShell, which has been done for years in all languages. As for PowerShell, measuring code execution time is a well-documented thing, all over the web. Just search for it. There are several examples in the built-in help files as well.

> ['powershell timer object'](https://www.bing.com/search?q=powershell%20timer%20object&form=ANNTH1&refig=4fb9259c75714a57b965f0bc32b3a1fa&sp=-1&pq=powershell%20timer%20objec&sc=1-22&qs=n&sk=&cvid=4fb9259c75714a57b965f0bc32b3a1fa)
>
> ['powershell how long command runs'](https://www.bing.com/search?q=powershell%20how%20long%20command%20runs&qs=AS&pq=powershell%20how%20long%20&sc=8-20&cvid=A674BD552EEA429FAFDB58384E1F37FE&FORM=QBRE&sp=1)
>
> [Quick-Hits: How Long Did That Last Command Take?](https://learn-powershell.net/2012/06/26/quick-hits-how-long-did-that-last-command-take/)

Anyway, just write your script to use a timer. Start the timer at code start, check for completion, end the timer ...

> [Using a StopWatch in PowerShell](https://ephos.github.io/posts/2018-8-20-Timers)

```
Start-Process -FilePath 'C:\Windows\System32\calc.exe'
Start-Sleep -Seconds 5

do
{
    Write-Output -InputObject 'Checking if calculator is running...'
    $calcProcess = Get-Process -Name Calculator -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    if ($calcProcess)
    {
        Write-Output -InputObject ('Calculator is running, PID {0}' -f $calcProcess.Id)
    }
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 5
}
until (-not $calcProcess)
```

or use ...

```
Measure-Command
```

Or

```
New-TimeSpan
```

Example(s):

[Powershell: Measuring Cmdlet Execution Time with Measure-Command](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/14292.powershell-measuring-cmdlet-execution-time-with-measure-command.aspx)

```
Measure-Command {Get-Process}
New-TimeSpan -Start (get-process notepad).StartTime
```

Comment: The process is encrypting _multiple_ files and I want to check how long it took to encrypt _one_ file, so starting a timer object to check if process is running does not help. And I would show what I have tried if I knew if it's even possible to do it and where to start, which is why I asked the question.

Comment: You just encrypt one file at a time using a loop to get them all, thus measuring at each loop pass.